# Does "Peek" happen earlier than a "Receive" in an Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, listener, monitor, servicebus, peek

In my team we have a Azure service bus account which is heavily used by multiple consumers. We have multiple topics and subscriptions under this service bus account. There are several listeners (performing receive operations) targeting each of these subscriptions.

There is a recent task where we have to log the sizes of the incoming messages for audit purposes. Couldnt find a way to find that (or atleast the maximum message size) through any of the metrics in the Azure Monitor. I am planning to write a new listener for these topics which will read and log them. This new listener will be performing peek operations only. (Before anyone comments, we Cant touch the existing listeners). Can someone confirm if there is a way for the peek listener to act ahead of the the receive listener, so that we do not miss any of the messages?

N.B.: Any other way of figuring the message size for a given interval is also appreciated (especially if it can be done through any of the metrics).  Unfortunately the metric "size" in the Azure monitor for Service bus signifies the size of a topic or queue rather than the message size

Comment: Instead of doing this, can't you create a catch-all kind of Subscription where all messages are sent by default (apart from being sent to existing Subscriptions)?

Comment: unfortunately cannot tweak the service bus schema at all.. If i had the option, then I would have added logging to all the existing listeners.  but all that I can do is to set up an additional  listener and configure  metrics.